# Using select statement with if condition in HIve, to populate another column

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

columns: `hp(numerical values)`, `power_rate(empty/NULL)`.

```
if hp>70

 power_rate column should be populated as 'powerful'

else

 power_rate should be 'moderate'
```

How do I achieve this using Hive?

Answer (score 4):

Using `case` statement:

```
insert overwrite table 
select hp, case when hp>70 then 'powerful' else 'moderate' end as power_rate
  from table
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate a column in a new table (without editing the existing table) there is a way,

```
CREATE TABLE <new_table_name> SELECT hp, CASE WHEN hp>70 THEN 'powerful' ELSE 'moderate' END AS power_rate from <previous_table_name>
```

**Note:** Here both tables are creating in the same database. *If you want to populate an existing table refer the above answer posted by @leftjoin*